# How to echo previously selected option in drop down first?

Tags: php, html-select

I am using the follow bit below.  I am first querying the db to see all available options but this is for an edit form so i want the drop down to show the previously selected value so i did another query and got the selection.  When i do it the way i have it below it will keep repeating the previously selected selection after each available option.  HOw to fix this?

```
<option>Select Sales rep</option>
<?php

$query="select agent_id, agent_name from agent_names where agent_id='$ad' 
order by agent_name asc";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while(list($agent_id, $agent_name)=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<option value=\"".$previousname."\">".$previousselection."</option>
    <option value=\"".$agent_id."\">".$agent_name."</option>";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check if `$agent_id` equals `$previousname` (perhaps you mean `$previousid`?) and echo selected="selected" if so:

```
while(list($agent_id, $agent_name)=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $selected = $agent_id == $previousname;
    echo "<option " . ($selected ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "") . " value=\"".$agent_id."\">".$agent_name."</option>";
}
```

Another option is to output the previous selected item before your while loop, and exclude it in your sql query.

Answer (score 1):

you should take the previos selection out of the while.. like this:

```
<?php

$query="select agent_id, agent_name from agent_names where agent_id='$ad' 
order by agent_name asc";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo "<option value=\"".$previousname."\">".$previousselection."</option>";
while(list($agent_id, $agent_name)=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<option value=\"".$agent_id."\">".$agent_name."</option>";
}


?>
```

and maybe even add an if so it wont repeat it self:

```
$query="select agent_id, agent_name from agent_names where agent_id='$ad' 
order by agent_name asc";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo "<option value=\"".$previousname."\">".$previousselection."</option>";
while(list($agent_id, $agent_name)=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  if ($agent_id != $previousname) {
    echo "<option value=\"".$agent_id."\">".$agent_name."</option>";
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can force MySQL to return your desired result first in the list like this:

```
$query = "SELECT agent_id, agent_name FROM agent_names WHERE agent_id='$ad' 
ORDER BY agent_id = '{$previousname}' DESC, agent_name ASC";
```

This tells MySQL first to sort by `agent_id` matching previous selection (i.e. it will be `1` for the previously selected record and `0` for all others, hence sorting by it `DESC` makes it first in the list. And since all others will have this fields equal to `0`, they will be sorted by second field, which is `agent_name ASC`